# A polynomial question, with 25th degree.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials

Find the P (x) polynomial with 25th degree and constant term 25, passing through points (1, –1), (2, –2),…, (25, –25).

I have never solved a question with the 25th degree! I am an university student and this is highschool question. I am a bit ashamed of myself :(

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I wrongly sent it. I just edited before even seeing your comment. Thanks

Comment: [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969). – Can you think of *any* (simple) polynomial passing through the prescribed points? Can you think of a way to modify that (perhaps by adding another polynomial) such that it still passes through the prescribed points, but has degree $25$?

Comment: what else is equal to the constant term...

Comment: This could help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial are a straightforward way of constructing such polynomials. It looks scary at first but the idea is simple and the computations are straightforward in practice.

Comment: Thanks guys for the idea and link I will try to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(x)=c(x-1)(x-2)...(x-25)-x$, where c is yet to be determined. It is given that $25= -25!c$ i.e. $c=-\dfrac{1}{24!}$, thus the desired polynomial is $P(x)=-\dfrac{1}{24!}(x-1)(x-2)...(x-25)-x$.

Comment: since the constant value is 25 the final polynomial shouldn't it be like this: P(x)=−124!(x−1)(x−2)...(x−25)−25. instead, "P(x)=−124!(x−1)(x−2)...(x−25)−x."

Comment: Did you mean $P(x)=-\dfrac{1}{24!}(x-1)...(x-25)-25$ in your first one? Its constant term is $-\dfrac{1}{24!}(-1)(-2)..(-25)-25=\dfrac{25!}{24!}-25=25-25=0$.

Comment: Yes. I meant the last x should be 25. Because in the question it says the constant is "25"? So the correct one is x or 25? If it is x, why?

Comment: @AdileCetinkaya Well if it's 25, I've shown the constant would be 0, not 25. If it's x, what would the constant term be? Hint: It is the same as P(0).

Comment: @Divide1918 Okay I got you. It is just suprised me that the answer is just this and that tricky :)

Comment: @AdileCetinkaya In this type of problem one has to really mind which term it is, e.g. is it the coefficient of $x^3$ or the constant term?

Comment: @Divide1918 it is not constant term? I assume :)

Comment: @AdileCetinkaya My last comment has nothing to do with this particular question you posted, it's just an example of where you might trip doing this type of problems.

Comment: @Divide1918 okay thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few things of note:

1. The constant term (25),  is the value of the polynomial when $x=0$
2. The difference $P(1)-P(0)=-26$ is the sum of coefficients ( not counting the  constant term)
3. Assuming it were an integer coefficient polynomial, that shows us an even number (including possibly 0) coefficients are odd, pushing parity ( even or odd) output to the constant term.
4. That would make $P(2)$ odd, but that's incorrect, so it can't be a strictly integer coefficient polynomial.
5. **Sequences of difference fails here**, as all your outputs shown are on $y=-x$ but that's not a degree 25 polynomial.